# Github actions use output of one workflow run onto the next workflow run

Tags: github, github-actions

In Github Actions is the following scenario possible

WORKFLOW1 workflow1.yaml ---> output x --> WORKFLOW2 workflow2.yaml
WORKFLOW1 Calculates a value x              WORKFLOW2 Uses the calculated value x e.g (a +x) = total
which is output from previous WORKFLOW1

P.S The first run workflow1 should not be called again as the value of x may change.
Any tips would be highly appreciated
Thanks

I have tried reusable workflows but it seems to run the workflow which calculates a new value of x and runs the entire workflow 1 again which we don't want we just need the output of wf1 to be used in wf2

Thanks

Comment: While triggering the `WORKFLOW2` you can pass INPUT values.

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to call the `workflow 2` from the `workflow 1` using a dispatch event.

The `workflow 2` trigger implementation would look like this:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      input_name:
        description: "description"
        required: true
```

You could send a `dispatch event` from the `workflow 1` by using the Github API:

On the official Github Documentation, there is a service to [create a workflow dispatch event](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event)

Here is a curl example:

```bash
- run: |
   curl \
     -X POST \
     -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>"\   # if needed
     -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
    https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/workflows/WORKFLOW_ID/dispatches \
     -d '{"ref":"main","inputs":{"input_name":"input_value"}}'
```

You can also find more references about this [in this article](https://www.enekoalonso.com/articles/issue-7).

Comment: Will this cause the second job to be triggered immediately The problem is our second job runs after a while independently ,After out testers are happy with it we can't have a second job getting triggered after the first workflow run finishes. Its like we want to assign a value to a variable and use that variable across workflows

Comment: The second workflow will be triggered at the moment the first workflow sends the request, so if it's at the middle of the workflow run, both could eventually run in parallel. If it's at the end, it will seems in sequence.

Comment: Yes in our case the second workflow runs independently,If only the output from WF1 can be stored as a variable somehow and that variable be used in WF2 .That would be so awesome

Comment: That's exactly what you will achieve with this example using inputs. You can even store them in env variables on the `Workflow 2` afterwards.

Comment: I will check it out and get back . Thanks GuiFalourd